# Automapper mapping Enum to Class

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, automapper

I get the generic error of 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.' when I try to create this map. Any ideas?

```
     Mapper.CreateMap<MyEnum, MyClass>().ConvertUsing(c =>
     {
        MyAttribute attribute = c.GetCustomAttribute<MyEnum, MyAttribute>();
        return new MyClass()
        {
           Id = c.ToString(),
           Name = attribute == null ? c.ToString() : attribute.DisplayName
        };
     });
```

And...

```
  protected override void Configure()
  {
     base.Configure();

     Mapper.CreateMap<MyEnum, MyClass>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ToString()))
        .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<DisplayNameResolver>());
  }

  private class DisplayNameResolver : ValueResolver<MyEnum, string>
  {
     protected override string ResolveCore(MyEnum e)
     {
        MyAttribute attribute = e.GetCustomAttribute<MyEnum, MyAttribute>();
        return attribute == null ? e.ToString() : attribute.DisplayName;
     }
  }
```

Don't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One symptom of this error is that you did not call the Configure() in your application root. If there is a problem with your configuration.. I would suggest you make a Unit test and call Automapper's `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` - [Configuration Validation Page](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation)

```
[TestMethod]
public void BaseMapperWorks()
{   
    //MapperConfig is my static MapperCongfiguration Class
    MapperConfig.Configure();
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

AutoMapper Validatior will give you everything that is wrong with your mappings